# Data not ordering chronological in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Using aggregation, I'm getting data per day of month. In this example, the data I'm getting is from 2020-05-28 to 2020-06-04. The data is ok, what its not is the order, since its not doing it chronologically because it goes from 1 to 4 and then skips to 28, as in the example below:

```
{'_id': 1, 'count': 205}
{'_id': 2, 'count': 128}
{'_id': 3, 'count': 142}
{'_id': 4, 'count': 116}
{'_id': 28, 'count': 165}
{'_id': 29, 'count': 203}
{'_id': 30, 'count': 173}
{'_id': 31, 'count': 202}
```

This is how it should work:

```
{'_id': 28, 'count': 165}
{'_id': 29, 'count': 203}
{'_id': 30, 'count': 173}
{'_id': 31, 'count': 202}
{'_id': 1, 'count': 205}
{'_id': 2, 'count': 128}
{'_id': 3, 'count': 142}
{'_id': 4, 'count': 116}
```

Any guess? Thank you for your help.

Aggregation:

```
[{$match: {
  start_date: {
    $gte: ISODate('2020-05-28T10:00:01.000Z'),
    $lte: ISODate('2020-06-04T09:59:59.000Z')
  }
}}, {$project: {
  'day': {
      '$dayOfMonth': {
          'date': '$start_date',
          'timezone': 'America/Mexico_City'
      }
  }
}}, {$group: {
  '_id': '$day',
    'count': {
        '$sum': 1
    }
}}, {$sort: {
  '_id': 1
}}]
```

Comment: 28 is greater than 4, so `{$sort: {'_id': 1 }}` will put it in that order.  You will need to construct that data differently to sort differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We could do something like this**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      start_date: {
        $gte: ISODate("2020-05-28T10:00:01.000Z"),
        $lte: ISODate("2020-06-04T09:59:59.000Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        month: {
          $month: {
            "date": "$start_date",
            "timezone": "America/Mexico_City"
          }
        },
        day: {
          $dayOfMonth: {
            "date": "$start_date",
            "timezone": "America/Mexico_City"
          }
        },
        year: {
          $year: {
            "date": "$start_date",
            "timezone": "America/Mexico_City"
          }
        }
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "_id.year": 1,
      "_id.month": 1,
      "_id.day": 1
    }
  }
])
```

---

*For your scenario it needs to be grouped by a full date so that `same dates with different month/year` can be distinguished.*

---

You can see the working example here
https://mongoplayground.net/p/qOoG-3V-S1P

Answer (score 1):

When you do the $group stage, you create a new `_id` which is an ordinary integer. As the comment on your question pointed out, the order you're seeing is logical, 1, 2, 3, 4, 28. It's not a date anymore, it's just a number.

To sort by date, you'll need to both keep the full date in your projection and sort by it.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      start_date: {
        $gte: ISODate("2020-05-28T10:00:01.000Z"),
        $lte: ISODate("2020-06-04T09:59:59.000Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "day": {
        "$dayOfMonth": {
          "date": "$start_date",
          "timezone": "America/Mexico_City"
        }
      },
      // Keep the full, unedited date.
      start_date: 1,
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$day",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "start_date": {
        // For every record, keep the lowest date timestamp
        // $first, $last, $max could be used too, they're all
        // different times on the same date.
        $min: "$start_date",
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      // Sort by date, rather than the integer that represents
      // only the day portion
      "start_date": 1
    }
  }
])
```

If you don't want `start_date` in your output, add another projection stage to remove it *after* sorting.